# PDFKit annotation saving text annotation

Tags: swift, pdf, pdfkit

I have a 100 page PDF document that my app opens up. In my document there are various textfield that I have added to allow the user to add comments. I have tried various ways to save the text in the textboxes to allow the user to return tp editing/marking up the document, but I am without luck. How can I save the text in the `PDFAnotoation` TextBox as an annotated string to allow the user to pickup where they left off when editing?

Here is my original:

```
var textFieldMultiline21 = PDFAnnotation()    
let textFieldMultilineBounds21 = CGRect(x: 27, y: 58+2, width: 339, height: 508)
textFieldMultiline21 = PDFAnnotation(bounds: textFieldMultilineBounds21, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget.rawValue), withProperties: nil)
textFieldMultiline21.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.text.rawValue)
textFieldMultiline21.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
textFieldMultiline21.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
textFieldMultiline21.isMultiline = true
page.addAnnotation(textFieldMultiline21)
```

Here I say attempt in saving the text inside the text boxes:

```
document.page(at: 21)?.annotations[0].contents = "Sample text"
textFieldMultiline21.caption = "sampletext"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat of a simple answer that was hiding in plain sight

**Reading Text**

```
pdfAnnotationTextField.value(forAnnotationKey: .widgetValue)
```

returns a string value with attributes

**Setting Text**

```
pdfAnnotationTextField.setValue("Enter Text", forAnnotationKey: .widgetValue)
```